# Convert ObjectResult<int?> into List<int>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have written a stored procedure :-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_USERSTORYDATA_EXISTS
    @MyWizardUserStoryId INT
   ,@ProjectId INT
   ,@StoryTitle NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM USERSTORY WHERE [MyWizardUserStoryId]=@MyWizardUserStoryId AND ProjectId=@ProjectId)
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM USERSTORY WHERE [MyWizardUserStoryId]=@MyWizardUserStoryId AND ProjectId=@ProjectId AND Title=@StoryTitle)
        BEGIN
            SELECT 0;
        END
        ELSE
         BEGIN
            SELECT 1;
        END
    END
    ELSE
         BEGIN
            SELECT 1;
        END

END
GO
```

I have consumed this procedure via Entity framework :-

```
List<Int32>lst=context.GET_USERSTORYDATA_EXISTS(MyWizardUserStoryId,ProjectId,storyTitle);
```

but its giving me error:-

```
Can not implicitly convert type 'ObjectResult<int?>' to List<int>
```

Comment: How about `.ToList()`?

Comment: How did you define this procedure in your context?? The procedure is returning a scalar value, not a set of numbers. You should define it as a scalar method

Comment: Besides, *why* did you create this stored procedure? Checking for existence before performing another operation simply increases the cost. You can use a `WHERE` clause in almost any other query and read/modify the data only if the condition holds

Comment: Why do you want to return a `List<int>` rather than `int`? _`List<int>` is helpful for returning **multiple** integers - but this stored proc will only ever return one of them._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [`ObjectResult<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn159793(v=vs.113).aspx) implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can use [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx). However, you also need to convert from nullable int. Easiest way would be to project using a Linq `Select` and then `ToList`. This code will replace any null values with zero:

```
List<Int32> lst = context
    .GET_USERSTORYDATA_EXISTS(MyWizardUserStoryId, ProjectId, storyTitle)
    .Select(i => i.GetValueOrDefault(0))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I needed to do a similar conversion but didn't want any default results at all, so I ended up adding an additional .Where(i => i != 0) before the .ToList(). There's probably a better way but this works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an object result to list I'd add a ToList() but in your case I don't think it's going to work since you're only returning an integer from the stored procedure.

Answer (score -3):

```
List<Int32?> list1 =new List<int?>() { 1, null, 2 };
                List<Int32> list2 = new List<int>();
                foreach (var item in list1)
                {
                    if (item.HasValue)
                        list2.Add(item.Value);
                }
```

Comment: First, you are *still* trying to assing an ObjectResult to a List variable. Second, returning a List from a Queryable is the job of ToList